# How to remove Routine Group error from workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench and I am trying to create a routine. However, At the time of creating routine some error comes,then i deleted that routine. Now I synchronize the model with the existing database, the Routine group error is coming, though i remove that  routine group. Can anyone help me how to remove this error from Model?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The _SYNTAX_ERROR suffix is added by MySQL Workbench to indicate that it found a syntax error in your routine code. Once you fixed that the name will change back to what you gave it. And then you can also synchronize your model.

Comment: The problem is, that the routineGroup is deleted. It is no where accessible, but still somewhere in the model file... Facing the same issue currently.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, cause i copy&pasted some c# code into a routine group, and it immediately became invisible by workbench. Synchronization now always reporte errors, even after deleting the whole routine group. The faulty code was stuck somewhere, inaccessible through the Workbench UI.

Just found a solution atm:

Do a regular synchronization and tell Workbench to change the sync-direction on the error entries. This will remove the faulty lines of code, even if they are not accessible through the Workbench UI.

[image]